# Onclick Event with Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

im trying to implement a onClick event to a navbar in css. This is my code so far:

```
<div id="nav">
                               <ul>
                              <li class = "cat1">
                                  <a href="#">Jahr</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "cat2">
                                  <a href="#">Monat</a>
                                  <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">Januar</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Februar</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">März</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">April</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Mai</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Juni</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Juli</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">August</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">September</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Oktober</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">November</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Dezember</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "catKultur">
                                  <a href="#">Kunst & Kultur</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "catParty">
                                  <a href="#">Party& Nachtleben</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "catSport">
                                  <a href="#">Sport</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "catKonzert">
                                  <a href="#">Konzert</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class = "catEssen">
                                  <a href="#">Essen & Trinken</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgbn33pv/

but the problem is, that i want to stay the button in red color after i clicked on it and that its switching back in grey after I clicked it again. It this realizable with css and can I check the button state to filter the maincontent?

regards

Comment: Click events are handled by Javascript not CSS.

Comment: You can do tricks with ':active', but the problem is stay the status of active.

Comment: Possible solutions: Pure JS (http://jsfiddle.net/1LLL839u/1/), jQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/a05hju0a/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly CSS does not have an onclick function the best you could hope for in CSS is :active but once you release the mouse button everything goes back to its original state. This is an example of the :active in action

```
<div id="button">
</div>

#button{
width:150px;
height:50px;
margin:50px auto;
background:#555;
}
#button:active{
background:#f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgbn33pv/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery :-

```js
$('#nav li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Add following css :-

```css
#nav li.active{
    background: red !important;
}
```